# Upload any file in PHP with security

Tags: php, file, security, upload, header

I want to make upload center and I allow to upload all files(even .php, .bat,....)
But I have to do something that cannot be running, for example, the user uploads 'index.php' in 'site.com/20190520/52.php' address then I want if everybody going to 'site.com/20190520/52.php' the PHP code doesn't run actually everybody can only download and cannot run.

another example:
I upload 'a.html' in 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/433604751326838794/555138662237732894/a.html' and if you going here it isn't running 
I want to do that.

Tip: I think we should change the file header but how?

Comment: save the files in a private directory. Them if someone tries to access `site.com/20190520/52.php` just do a `readfile(PRIVATE_DIR . '/20190520/52.php');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested you can store it in a private directory, ideally somewhere out of the WEB_ROOT of your server. A few things to consider with this approach.

1. Make sure the file system permissions are appropriately set for that directory.
2. When handling requests for the file, `site.com/20190520/52.php` make sure you are protecting against directory traversal. i.e make sure the attacker cant do something like `site.com/20190520/../../../../../../etc/passwd`
3. Unless every file will be accessible by everyone, be sure to consider how you plan to authenticate/authorize requests.

You may also consider approaching this from a system level. Store the files in a private directory, and set up a separate web server (vhost, etc) on a subdomain that will serve the files. It can be configured to not execute any files. Your web server (nginx, apache, etc) will dictate how you configure this.

Another thought may be to look into leveraging a CDN service. These services will expose an API to you, so your user uploads the file, you get it on your server and send it to the CDN. Depending on the performance you're looking for this may easiest and fastest option that will scale well.